# Proof of Jacobi fraction expansion in Triple Product Proof

Tags: analysis, elliptic-functions, theta-functions

In the proof of Jacobi's triple product identity by Jacobi, he considers the infinite product; $\frac{1}{(1-qz)(1-q^2z)...}$
and expands it into 1 + $\frac{B_1z}{(1-qz)}$ +  $\frac{B_2z^2}{(1-qz)(1-q^2z)}$ + ..

How did Jacobi know such a product could be expanded in such a way?

Comment: Because he proved it! What are you really asking?

Comment: Jacobi was very expert in formal manipulation (almost like an ancestor of Ramanujan) and for him these things were quite routine. You may study the proof given in Jacobi's *Fundamenta Nova*. I have found it to be much simpler compared to other proofs offered later.

Comment: My bet is that both Jacobi and Ramanujan were able to make intelligent guesses about the visible form of a formula and verify its correctness (or falsity) rapidly. That was their key expertise. It's very difficult to figure out if there is systematic procedure behind all this.

Comment: Oh thank you that clears up everything.